# How can I fix this error? there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "products"

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE order_items 
(
    order_id int,
    product_id int,
    quantity int,

    CONSTRAINT order_items_pk 
        PRIMARY KEY(order_id,product_id),
    CONSTRAINT order_items_order_id_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY(order_id) REFERENCES orders(id),
    CONSTRAINT order_items_product_id_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Because different RDBMS systems vary so much, we ask you to [edit] your post and put in tags for the system you use. Like [tag:sql-server], [tag:postgrsql],[tag:oracle]. [tag:mysql] and so forth.

Comment: without showing us the table products we can only summize that you have no column primary key id filed or at least a unique or Key constraint

Comment: Define the `order` and `products` tables first. Side note: Unless you're using ruby on rails, which is the only framework that expects entities to be named in the plural, best practice is to name your tables in the singular, ie `order`, `product` and `order_item` etc. It makes sense if you think about the syntax for a column `product.name` reads easily and makes sense, and `products.name` does not read easily or make sense.

Answer (score 2):

To create this table, you will first have to create the tables mentioned in the foreign key declarations. Those tables are `orders` and `products`.

If you don't create those tables first, the table server cannot handle those constraints.

Comment: thanks for your help but those tables are already created but still the error continue raising. so I don`t know what to do.